# i cant get my pson xp 235 working

Tags: printer

For my girlfriend I’ve put elementary on her slow windows computer.

It is beautiful but her `Epson XP-235` don't work!

Of course I’ve tried the normal way to make it print but there are no drivers. I guess, it's not in the list of Epson printers and also not listed in the open source site. I don't know how to get it installed when I downloaded it from the Epson website.

I get the driver but it don't get it installed.

Is it possible for someone to give me a [apt](/questions/tagged/apt) command so i can easily get it working?

Bernard

p.s. i'm dutch, if anyone can give me an answer in dutch it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using loki search for your printer in this site http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/ and then download this three files:

ESC/P-R Driver amd64 deb

Epson Printer Utility amd64 deb

All-in-one package Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit

Put them on the Downloads folder.

---

Install the gdebi package:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gdebi

---

Install by the order above the first two files:

sudo apt-get update

sudo gdebi Downloads/"file name".deb

sudo apt-get update

---

Install the third file by doing this:

sudo apt-get update

cd Downloads

tar xavf "file name".deb.tar.gz

This will create a new folder.

cd "new folder name"

./install.sh

sudo apt-get update

---

reboot the computer and your printer should be working

Answer (score 0):

Well I could activate the printer.

But when I print ie. LibreOffice Write document I've got the following message:

> Der Drucker konnte nicht gestartet werden. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre
>   Druckerkonfiguration.

(it's German - it means)

> The printer couldn't be started, please check your printer configuration

, any idea?